# DocuSign API Windows Service "Fail to resolve SendOnBehalfOf user"

Tags: docusignapi

I'm trying to create a Windows service to go out and download documents and envelope information using the DocuSign API.  I've run into one error that I don't know how to go about fixing.

The message written to the error log says "System.ServiceModel.FaultException: This User lacks sufficient permissions. Fail to resolve SendOnBehalfOf user".

I checked in the DocuSign console and under the DocuSign API section Account-Wide Rights, Send On Behalf Of Rights, Sequential Signing are all checked.

I'm a little confused as to why it's trying to resolve a SendOnBehalfOf user since I'm not trying to send anything.

Here's the relevant section of code:

```
string auth = "<DocuSignCredentials><Username>" + DSuserName
 + "</Username><Password>" + password
 + "</Password><IntegratorKey>" + key
 + "</IntegratorKey></DocuSignCredentials>";

DocuSignAPI.DSAPIServiceSoapClient client = new DSAPIServiceSoapClient();

using (OperationContextScope scope = new OperationContextScope(client.InnerChannel))
{
  HttpRequestMessageProperty httpRequestProperty = new HttpRequestMessageProperty();
httpRequestProperty.Headers.Add("X-DocuSign-Authentication", auth);
OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageProperties[HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name] =   httpRequestProperty;


Envelope test = new Envelope();
test = client.RequestEnvelope(envelopeID, false);

string envelopeData = envelopeID + "|" + test.CustomFields[0].Value.ToString();
envelopeData = envelopeData.Replace("|", ",");

EnvelopePDF envPDF = new EnvelopePDF();
envPDF = client.RequestPDFWithCert(envelopeID, false);
}
```

Here's what I've got from the trace:

```
<E2ETraceEvent xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/E2ETraceEvent">
<System xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/windows/eventlog/system">
<EventID>0</EventID>
<Type>3</Type>
<SubType Name="Information">0</SubType>
<Level>8</Level>
<TimeCreated SystemTime="2013-11-22T19:07:59.3523309Z" />
<Source Name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging" />
<Correlation ActivityID="{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}" />
<Execution ProcessName="DocuSignService" ProcessID="8620" ThreadID="7" />
<Channel />
<Computer>OPSITLAP03</Computer>
</System>
<ApplicationData>
<TraceData>
<DataItem>
<MessageLogTraceRecord Time="2013-11-22T14:07:59.3523309-05:00" Source="TransportSend" Type="System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.OperationFormatter+OperationFormatterMessage" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/ServiceModel/Management/MessageTrace">
<Addressing>
<Action>http://www.docusign.net/API/3.0/RequestEnvelope</Action>
<To>https://www.docusign.net/api/3.0/dsapi.asmx</To>
</Addressing>
<HttpRequest>
<Method>POST</Method>
<QueryString></QueryString>
<WebHeaders>
<X-DocuSign-Authentication><DocuSignCredentials><Username>"[IntegratorKey]UserID"</Username><Password>"Password"</Password><IntegratorKey>"IntegratorKey"</IntegratorKey></DocuSignCredentials></X-DocuSign-Authentication>
</WebHeaders>
</HttpRequest>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<RequestEnvelope xmlns="http://www.docusign.net/API/3.0">
<EnvelopeID>50be5ed0-ece2-44ea-bfbd-53c02e81e916</EnvelopeID>
<IncludeDocumentBytes>false</IncludeDocumentBytes>
</RequestEnvelope>
</s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
</MessageLogTraceRecord>
</DataItem>
</TraceData>
</ApplicationData>
</E2ETraceEvent>
```

Comment: Are you positive you are not setting any other headers in the request?  I would do a SOAP dump of the request to see exactly what you are sending out.

Comment: @Ergin I added the trace data to the original post.

Comment: So who are you inputting for the value of UserID?  You can only request envelopes that belong to you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your trace shows the value of the **X-DocuSign-Authentication** header as:

```
<DocuSignCredentials><Username>"[IntegratorKey]UserID"</Username><Password>"Password"</Password><IntegratorKey>"IntegratorKey"</IntegratorKey></DocuSignCredentials>
```

Not sure why the value you're using for **Username** seems to be prefaced with "[IntegratorKey]". I'd suggest that you try just using the email address that's associated with the user's login credentials -- and don't preface with "[IntegratorKey]".  For example:

```
<DocuSignCredentials><Username>johndoe@example.com</Username><Password>johnspassword</Password><IntegratorKey>TEST-eae5f282-k7c2-59b2-b293-1c4cf55c76def</IntegratorKey></DocuSignCredentials>
```

Comment: I was using the Key at the beginning because the example I had did that.  However after looking more closely at the log files I was creating, the username was being passed as blank (it was being set earlier in the code and getting cleared somehow).  Once I changed it to the email address (hardcoded) I was able to get in and get envelopes.  Thanks to both you and Ergin for your help.

Answer (score 0):

When using the `RequestEnvelope` api call the envelope must be owned by the API user.  Since it doesn't appear you are trying to use SOBO functionality that's most likely causing your issue.

Comment: The UserID is the same as the one that created the envelope from what I can tell.

Comment: You should test with email address instead of the UserId in GUID format, to make sure.  Just wire up a quick test through demo.docusign.net and you should be able to test pretty quickly...